# IPA in math mode

Tags: math-mode, tipa

I want to use an IPA character as a symbol in a mathematical formula in my latex document (it sounds perverse, but there's a reason). But when I do `$\textipa{I}$`, I get the large capital I instead of the small capital I, and when I do `$\textipa{\textrtails}$`, I get nothing. Can someone help me?

Here's a minimal not working example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tipa}
\begin{document}
\textipa{I\textrtails} $\textipa{I\textrtails}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know if that helps, but if you load the amsmath package and do `$\text{\textipa{I\textrtails}}$`, the symbol will appear.

Comment: @marmot That mostly works, but it doesn't render the IPA in the mathy-italics. But thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you try

```
$\textit{\textipa{I\textrtails}}$
```

to obtain the slanted versions of `\textipa{I}` and `\textipa{\textrtails}` while in math mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\textipa{I\textrtails} 
$\textrm{\textipa{I\textrtails}}$
{\itshape \textipa{I\textrtails}}
$\textit{\textipa{I\textrtails}}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not at stake with math symbol fonts, you can define the proper math setting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{tipa}

\DeclareSymbolFont{tipa}{T3}{cmr}{m}{sl}
\SetSymbolFont{tipa}{bold}{T3}{cmr}{bx}{sl}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathrtails}{\mathord}{tipa}{249}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathsci}{\mathord}{tipa}{73}

\newcommand{\its}{{\mathsci\mathrtails}}

\begin{document}

\textsl{\textsci\textrtails}

$\mathsci\mathrtails+\its$

\textsl{\textbf{\textsci\textrtails}}

$\bm{\its}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

There is no need to load `tipa`, if you just need those symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\DeclareFontEncoding{T3}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{T3}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{tipa}{T3}{cmr}{m}{sl}
\SetSymbolFont{tipa}{bold}{T3}{cmr}{bx}{sl}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathrtails}{\mathord}{tipa}{249}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathsci}{\mathord}{tipa}{73}

\newcommand{\its}{{\mathsci\mathrtails}}

\begin{document}

$\mathsci\mathrtails+\its$

$\bm{\its}$

\end{document}
```